# objective-c - difference between char and unichar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, char, unichar

I searched a lot about the difference of `unichar` and `char` but did't get any clear concept.
also tell me difference about `char[]` and `unichar[]`.

when use `char` and `unichar` ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`char` is 8 bits and represents either an arbitrary 8-bit number, or a UTF-8 code unit, or a code unit in some other character encoding.

`unichar` is 16 bits and represents a UTF-16 code unit.

Answer (score 6):

unichar is twice the size of char.

unichar often used in other language codes:

difference for example:

`char a = 'y';` (correct)
`char a = '字';` (wrong)

`unichar a = '字';` （correct）

```
char a[2]  : 8bit * 2

unichar a[2] : 16bit *2
```

hope it helps.