# Problem parsing Strings with Russian chars

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, string, utf-8

I'm using an old objectiveC routine (let's call it oldObjectiveCFunction), which parses a String analyzing each char. After analyzing chars, it divides that String into Strings, and returns them into an array called *functions. This is a super reduced sample of how is that old function doing the String parse:

```
NSMutableArray *functions = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray *components = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableString *sb = [NSMutableString new];
char c;
int sourceLen = source.length;
int index = 0;

while (index < sourceLen) {
    c = [source characterAtIndex:index];
    //here do some random work analyzing the char 
    [sb appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",c]];
    if (some condition){
        [components addObject:(NSString *)sb];                 
        sb = [NSMutableString new];
        [functions addObject:[components copy]];
    }
}
```

later, I'm getting each String of *functions doing this with Swift code:

```
let functions = oldObjectiveCFunction(string) as? [[String]]
functions?.forEach({ (function) in
    var functionCopy = function.map { $0 }
    for index in 0..<functionCopy.count {
       let string = functionCopy[index]
    }
}
```

the problem is that, it works perfectly with normal strings, but if the String contains russian names, like this:

```
РАЦИОН
```

the output, the content of my `let string` variable, is this:

```
 \u{10}&\u{18}\u{1e}\u{1d}
```

How can I get the same Russian string instead of that?

I tried doing this:

```
let string2 = String(describing: string?.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8))
```

but it returns even more strange result:

```
"Optional([32, 16, 38, 24, 30, 29, 0])"
```

Comment: Do the strings look ok if you try to consume them in Objective-C instead of Swift?

Comment: I'd guess that `%c` means _8-bit unsigned character (unsigned char)_; try `%C` specifier _16-bit UTF-16 code unit (unichar)_.

Comment: @JosefZ it looks like you're correct about the `%c` vs. `%C`. You should post that as an answer, since an 8-bit unsigned character can't possibly hold Cyrillic characters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the supported Swift String format specifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52332747/what-are-the-supported-swift-string-format-specifiers)

Comment: @JosefZ I tryed and same error...

Comment: @DuncanC it didn't work

Comment: c = [source characterAtIndex:index]; is returning the bad char... how to solve it?

Comment: Declare `unichar c;` instead of `char c;` at 4th line (sorry, I don't speak _swift_ or _Objective-C_ so I'm not sure about correct  syntax).

Comment: thank you very much @JosefZ finally doing %C and unichar c in combination solved the problem. Please, post a solution, I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Analysis**. Sorry, I don't speak *swift* or *Objective-C* so the following example is given in Python; however, the 4th and 5th column (unicode reduced to 8-bit) recalls *weird* numbers in your question.

```
for ch in 'РАЦИОН':
   print(ch,                          # character itself
      ord(ch),                        # character unicode in decimal
      '{:04x}'.format(ord(ch)),       # character unicode in hexadecimal
      (ord(ch)&0xFF),                 # unicode reduced to 8-bit decimal
      '{:02x}'.format(ord(ch)&0xFF))  # unicode reduced to 8-bit hexadecimal
```

> ```
> Р 1056 0420 32 20
> А 1040 0410 16 10
> Ц 1062 0426 38 26
> И 1048 0418 24 18
> О 1054 041e 30 1e
> Н 1053 041d 29 1d
> ```

**Solution**. Hence, you need to fix all in your code *reducing* 16-bit to to 8-bit:

first, declare `unichar c;` instead of <strike>`char c;`</strike> at the 4th line, 
and use `[sb appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C",c]];` at the 11th line; note

- *Latin Capital Letter C* in `%C` specifier *16-bit UTF-16 code unit (unichar)* instead of
- <strike>*Latin Small Letter C* in `%c` specifier  *8-bit unsigned character (unsigned char)*</strike>;

**Resources**. My answer is based on answers to the following questions at SO:

- [What are the supported Swift String format specifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52332747/what-are-the-supported-swift-string-format-specifiers)
- [objective-c - difference between char and unichar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959374/)

Answer (score 0):

Your last result is not strange. The optional comes from the `string?`, and the `cString()` function returns an array of CChar ( Int8 ).

I think the problem comes from here - but I'm not sure because the whole thing looks confusing:

`[sb appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",c]];`

have you tried :

```
[sb appendString: [NSString stringWithCString:c encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Instead of stringWithFormat?

( The solution of the %C instead of %c proposed by your commenters looks a good idea too. ) - oops - just saw you have tried without success.

Comment: can you share how the line should be? I don't know how to deal with Objective C @Moose

Comment: your code gives me two errors: Use of undeclared identifier 'cString' and Unexpected interface name 'NSString': expected expression

Comment: :D sorry, I have mixed with swift ! I have get so used to it! I fix

Comment: did you fixed? it gives me exactly the same two errors, infact, it's the same line of code, you don't edited it?

Comment: oh @Moose now it's edited, but now gives me this error: Use of undeclared identifier 'encoding'

Comment: Sorry, it took me a while - I haven't typed objC for so long.

Comment: but it is still failing... Use of undeclared identifier 'encoding'

Comment: I let the comma between the two parameters - no comma in objC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228647/discussion-between-moose-and-nullpointerexception).